# Git merge from master commit message

Tags: git, branch, message

In general, when I merge a branch from the master branch git automatically generates a commit message like this :

```
Merge branch 'master' into name-of-my-branch
```

but last time it generates a commit  message like :

```
Merge branch 'master' of git.domain.com:repo-name
```

What caused this unexpected merge commit message?

Comment: Is this the entire commit message ? You don't have any "into XXX" part ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First git will leave out the "into xxx" part if that branch is "master".

The "of xxx" part usually comes from a `git pull` which merges the remote branch into the current branch.

In your case you were on your local master branch. You did some local commits and then did `git pull`, which merged upstream changes onto your master branch.

Have a look at `gitk` or `git log --graph` to get a better idea what is going on.

Also using `git pull --rebase` might be a good way to get rid of these additional (usually unwanted) merge commits. (I usually define `git config --global alias.up pull --rebase` and use `git up` afterwards to update my local branch.)